# Why do vote related badges update slowly or flakily?

Tags: bug, badges

I noticed that the count update and awarding of vote related badges like the following is slow / flaky:

1. Civic Duty
2. Vox Populi
3. Suffrage

For instance, one day I had completed 40 max votes, but the count showed 39 till the next day. And finally on the next day after a few more votes the Vox Populi badge was awarded.

Is there a bug or does the calculation take time or does it have to go through moderators to work?